# Control key + M on the keyboard triggers double-click functionality on Tree Items in SWT

Tags: java, treeview, swt

I have a double-click functionality for the tree viewers wherein the tree items expand\collapse when I double-click on them. That is completely fine but the issue is that when I press CTRL+M on the keyboard even then the tree items expand\collapse, I don't want this to happen. My code for double-clicking tree items is as follows:

```
private class DoubleClickListener implements IDoubleClickListener
{
  @Override
  public void doubleClick(final DoubleClickEvent event)
  {
    final IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)event.getSelection();
    if (selection == null || selection.isEmpty())
      return;

    final Object sel = selection.getFirstElement();

    final ITreeContentProvider provider = (ITreeContentProvider)treeViewer.getContentProvider();

    if (!provider.hasChildren(sel))
      return;

    if (treeViewer.getExpandedState(sel))
      treeViewer.collapseToLevel(sel, AbstractTreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS);
    else
      treeViewer.expandToLevel(sel, 1);
  }
}
```

This behavior (CTRL+m expanding tree items) only happens When I use the  IDoubleClickListener interface and override the method  doubleClick(), but the same behavior  (CTRL+m expanding tree items) does not happen when I use : 
    addMouseListener(new MouseListener())
and override the method : 
    mouseDoubleClick(). 
Is the behavior (CTRL+m) expanding tree items related to IDoubleClickListener interface(If so what is the reason) or is this problem generic? I feel it should not be related to IDoubleClickListener, Can someone please tell me why is there a difference in using these two logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl+M is often treated the same as the Return key. The native tree control used by SWT usually treats Return as meaning expand / collapse the current tree node.

To stop this add a `KeyListener` to the tree and suppress the unwanted key events:

```
treeViewer.getTree().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
  {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent event)
    {
      if (event.keyCode == SWT.CR ||
          (event.keyCode == 'm' && event.stateMask == SWT.CTRL))
       {
         event.doit = false;
       }
    }
  });
```

Update:

Use:

```
if (e.keyCode == 'm' && e.stateMask == (SWT.CTRL | SWT.SHIFT))
```

to test for Ctrl+Shift+m

```
if (e.keyCode == 'm' && e.stateMask == SWT.CTRL)
```

to test for Ctrl+m

```
if (e.keyCode == SWT.CR)
```

to test for Enter.

Comment: Keycode is the actual key pressed, stateMask tells you if Ctrl or Alt or Cmd (Mac only) is also being pressed. There may be some variation on the events you get depending on the platform, I tested on a Mac.

Comment: That is really your design decision. You can make a class extending KeyAdapter rather than using a anonymous class so you don't have to repeat the code.

Comment: You will get one key event with Ctrl is pressed which should be ignored and a second event when Ctrl + m is pressed. If you don't want to deal with Enter remove the SWT.CR check.

Comment: @user3354299 that is a [**completely invalid edit suggestion**](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4811097). **Please do not do that!**

Comment: What do I do for capital letter 'M' ? Do I simply add another condition event.keyCode == 'M' or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: What do I do for capital letter 'M' ? Do I simply add another condition event.keyCode == 'M' or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: For Ctrl + Shift the `stateMask` will be `(SWT.CTRL | SWT.SHIFT)`

Comment: There will be three keys CTRL + SHIFT + M, How do I write the condition for this, the following works fine - if (((event.keyCode == 'm' || (event.keyCode == 'M' && event.stateMask == SWT.SHIFT) && event.stateMask== SWT.CTRL))). Is there a better way other than the preceding condition? I need a simpler way as the preceding condition looks a bit complicated.

Comment: @greg-449 Can you please look into my above comment?

Comment: one last question. is ctrl + m a retuen key in Windows OS or JAVA event code?

Comment: I don't know about Windows, they are different on a Mac.

Comment: @greg-449 This behavior (CTRL+m expanding tree items) only happens When I use the IDoubleClickListener interface and override the method doubleClick(), but the same behavior (CTRL+m expanding tree items) does not happen when I use :
    addMouseListener(new MouseListener())
and override the method : 
    mouseDoubleClick(). 
Is the behavior (CTRL+m) expanding tree items related to IDoubleClickListener interface(If so what is the reason) or is this problem generic? I feel it should not be related to IDoubleClickListener, Can you please tell me why is there a difference in using these two logic?

Comment: I have edited my question, Please look into it, Thanks.

Comment: Possibly something to do with the native control, since I don't have Windows I can't tell

Comment: Can u please ask someone on stack overflow to answer possible reasons? Since I'm new to stack overflow I cannot do it.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - Can you please look into the post.

Comment: You can only use @ to notify people who have commented on the question. Neither you nor I can message other SO users. Asking a new question is the only way to get more attention.